# How to fix ExternalContext call that corrupts xls file to download?

Tags: excel, jsf, jsf-2, download, xls

I have a method that generates report using jett and that shows the file download dialog for the user:

```
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    externalContext.responseReset();
    externalContext.setResponseContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + "precificacao.xls" + "\"");

    //map beans omitted

    FileOutputStream saida = null;
    try {
        saida = new FileOutputStream(getClass().getResource("/.").getPath() + "/precificacao.xls");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(getClass().getResource("/.").getPath() + "/precificacao.xls" + ": " + e.getMessage());
    }

    InputStream entrada = null;
    try {

        entrada = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(getClass().getResource("/template.xls").getFile()));

        ExcelTransformer transformer = new ExcelTransformer();
        Workbook workbook = transformer.transform(entrada, beans);
        workbook.write(saida);

        saida.flush();
        saida.close();

        facesContext.responseComplete();
    } //catch ommitted
```

the downloaded file has already been corrupted, as a text document and without any byte:
[print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w2NH.png)

Before this download dialog routine, xls was generated normally, so I think it's the setResponseContentType that I'm going through the wrong way though I saw the link in the right nomenclature for xls: http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types

Comment: what if you **don't** set the content type?

Comment: It comes corrupted in the same way ... I tried several different calls to ExternalContext and it always corrupts ... suggest something @Kukeltje ?

Comment: Suggesting to **debug** the response... What is the size, Is it empty? What if you download a fixed excel? What if you download a fixed PDF, what if you download a fixed image (all via this same construction). Eliminate things... narrow down the cause... Set breakpoints...

Comment: So did you solve it?

Comment: I'll post the answer

Comment: What answer? Wasn't mine correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this way

```
public void createRelatorioFichaTecnica(Produto produto) throws IOException {

FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
externalContext.responseReset(); 
externalContext.setResponseContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel"); 
externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + "precificacao.xls" + "\""); 

//map beans omitted
OutputStream saida = externalContext.getResponseOutputStream(); 
try{

    InputStream entrada = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(getClass().getResource("/template.xls").getFile())); 

    ExcelTransformer transformer = new ExcelTransformer(); 
    Workbook workbook = transformer.transform(entrada, beans); 
    workbook.write(saida);

    saida.flush();
    saida.close();

    facesContext.responseComplete();
 } 
 //catch omitted
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for accepting my answer and my investigation. Not sure if I'll put in the effort to analysing questions code again next time...

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You ***are*** aware that you nowhere write the contents of the excel to the response? So the response is effectively empty and hence causes all sorts of weird behaviour.

You even write this yourself:

> without any byte

And you have it in the image to...

You would have had the same problem with a PDF, or image or even a plain text file (although that would not have given an error but just be empty)

You would even have had the same problem with a plain servlet. So effectively all your tags (excel, jsf, jsf-2, xls) are not really related to the problem. Narrow things down.

Getting the outputstream from the context and writing the workbook to that stream should fix it.

```
OutputStream saida = externalContext.getResponseOutputStream();
```